# TabIndex not working with TextBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

**Issue:** I have added the following to `TextBox` control for some validation check:-

**1) onkeydown** = `"return isAlpha(event.keyCode)"`

**2) required**

Following is the complete textbox code:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="mname" runat="server" required type="text" TabIndex="2"   onkeydown = "return isAlpha(event.keyCode);" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and `isAlpha` function is:

```
isAlpha(keyCode) { return ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode==32) }
```

**Expected Result:** The `TabIndex` should work even after adding `onkeydown = "return isAlpha(event.keyCode);"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share  `isAlpha` code

Comment: function isAlpha(keyCode)
    {
         return ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode==32)
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip your validation for <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

You can achieve this by checking like this

```
function isAlpha(keyCode)
{
    return ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode==32 || keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 46 || (keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40) || keyCode == 46);
}
```

You should skip validations for

1. <kbd>backspace</kbd> - 8
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd> - 13
3. <kbd>Delete</kbd> - 46 also

Comment: replace your function with mine